# How to use ng build to generate ts, map and js files into the same folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used "ng new Sample" to generate a new Angular2 folder.
The version of Angular is 2.1.0.
The folder structure is:

```
angular-cli.json  
karma.conf.js      
package.json       
protractor.conf.js 
README.md          
tslint.json        
node_modules       
e2e                
src     
   ----app     
     ------app.component.css    
     ------app.component.html   
     ------app.component.spec.ts     
     ------app.component.ts     
     ------app.module.ts        
     ------index.ts
```

tsconfig.json file:

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/debug",
        "sourceMap": true,
        //"inlineSources": true,
        "rootDir": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
          "../node_modules/@types"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then I ran "ng build", the files below were output to the "dist" folder.
But in fact, I didn't set the folder "dist" in any of the config files.

```
              Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
      main.bundle.js    2.75 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
    styles.bundle.js    10.2 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
           inline.js    5.53 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
            main.map     2.8 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
          styles.map      14 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
          inline.map    5.59 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
          index.html  474 bytes          [emitted]
```

My question are how can I output the ts, map and js files into one folder separately using ng build while not using gulp? What's the inline.js? Why the files were output to the dist folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your folder you should have a file named:

```
angular-cli.json
```

Open this file  and go to:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

Change the path for the outDir folder.